# How should I escape '&&' and other special characters when running a bash command with read() or run()?

Tags: bash, julia

My code:

```
df = read(`df -h|grep /dev/sda1 && df -h|grep pCloud`, String)
```

When I run it I get the following message from Julia:

```
Warning: special characters "#{}()[]<>|&*?~;" should now be quoted in commands
 │   caller = #shell_parse#333(::String, ::Function, ::String, ::Bool) at shell.jl:100
 └ @ Base ./shell.jl:100
df: invalid option -- '|'
Try 'df --help' for more information.
ERROR: LoadError: failed
process: Process(`df '-h|grep' /dev/sda1 '&&' df '-h|grep' pCloud`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]
```

I have found someone having a similar [problem](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-quote-special-characters-in-run-function/21359),
but they seem to have resolved this issue without escaping.

Answer (score 11):

Julia commands are not run in a shell, so using shell features like that will not work. If you want to pipe from one command to another, you should use the `pipeline` function and if you want to test the success or failure of a command or pipeline, run it with the `success` function. In this case, you could do this:

```
success(pipeline(`df -h`, `grep /dev/sda1`)) &&
success(pipeline(`df -h`, `grep pCloud `))
```

Of course, in that case you could call `df -h` a single time and do

```
df = read(`df -h`, String)
contains(df, "/dev/sda1") && contains(df, "pCloud")
```